# Main class not found exception in jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I am trying to execute the performance-meters.jar according to the tutorial at 
http://marklogic.github.io/performance-meters/tutorial.html

using the command

```
java -cp performance-meters.jar:xcc.jar com.marklogic.performance.PerformanceMeters
```

I am getting the following error:

```
D:\MBS\performance-meters-master\performance-meters-master\classes>java -cp performance-meters.jar:xcc.jar com.marklogic.performance.PerformanceMeters
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/marklogic/performance/PerformanceMeters
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.marklogic.performance.PerformanceMeters
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.marklogic.performance.PerformanceMeters.  Program will exit.
```

I have kept both the jar files in the same folder.

Links to the jar files are:
http://developer.marklogic.com/code/performance-meters
[http://developer.marklogic.com/products/xcc][3]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using windows system or Unix? If windows then I think you need to use ; and not : in separtaing jars as follows:

Comment: java -cp performance-meters.jar ; xcc.jar com.marklogic.performance.PerformanceMeters

Comment: Thanks a lot Harish....what a silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use semicolon instead colon in your cp declaration.

```
java -cp performance-meters.jar;xcc.jar com.marklogic.performance.PerformanceMeters
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using windows system or Unix? If windows then I think you need to use `;` and not `:` in separating jars as follows:

```
java -cp performance-meters.jar ; xcc.jar com.marklogic.performance.PerformanceMeters
```